# Does the median of the residuals of a simple linear regression mean anything?

Tags: regression, residuals

I know that the mean of the residuals is 0, but what about the median?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but I lack the rep!

Under the assumptions of simple linear regression, the residuals should be normally distributed, and therefore symmetric, and therefore their median should be (statistically) the same as their mean. In practice, the sample median will deviate from the true median, but as your sample size grows large this should converge to 0. If it doesn't, then your residuals aren't symmetric, and you've got a problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the median of the residuals is equal to zero, although it can be. For example in 4 datasets in Anscombe's quartet, if we look at the median of the residuals from the linear regressions of y1 on x1, y2 on x2, y3 on x3, and y4 on x4, we see the medians are -0.04136, 0.1291, -0.2303, and 0.